# How to change the default sync folder on the win 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, sync, network-shares

I'd like to use Win 7's Sync applet to sync word processing, spreadsheet and other data files between multiple computers and a NAS device with the NAS being the primary repository of the data. Sync seems simple enuff to use but I do not want the local copies of the Sync'd files to be stored on the PC's "C" drives. I see no indication in any of the Sync help screens that tell the user how to change the default destination path for the local copies of the files. I do see where the user can manage the amount of disk space to make available etc but no way to change the default local data path. Anyone have any insight on how to accomplish this?  Thanx

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to be able to save files onto your C: drive, have them synced to your NAS, and then removed from the C: drive?

Comment: Kalaracy: Nope, actually I'm using an SSD for my C:/Boot drive and I want to keep all data/progs/etc off of it - only opsys files on my C:. Maybe an example is in order here;  I have a Data share on my NAS with a subfolder calledof Spreadsheets, I'd like create the same structure on my PC's E: drive and sync all files contained on the NAS subfolder 'Spreadsheets' onto the E:\Data\Spreadsheets folder

Comment: Kalarcy, ooops, sorry hit the 'enter' key b4 i was thru with my post. So i hope you understand what i'm wanting to accomplish with SYNC'ing my NAS data with my E: drive data.